# Is there a way to remove the gap under my Today Extension

Tags: ios, widget, ios8, ios8-extension, ios8-today-widget

Ok, I'm trying to make todays view extension and I would really like to make it have 77 pixels of height. But no matter what iOS keeps inserting a padding under my top view.

Like this:

[image: My view with borders]

You see, I'm calling setPreferredContentSize passing a height of 77. But the gap is always there. Even If I set my content size smaller, it gets cut, but the padding is still there and apparently with the same size, the image bellow illustrates:

[image]

Does someone have anything to say about this? I'm trying this because Evernote's widget seems to manage to remove that gap, but i'm really stuck, I even disabled autolayout, but nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the following:

`-(UIEdgeInsets)widgetMarginInsetsForProposedMarginInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)defaultMarginInsets {
  return UIEdgeInsetsMake(
    defaultMarginInsets.top, 
    defaultMarginInsets.left, 
    0,
    defaultMarginInsets.right );
}`